# How to write views and Controller for to save associated objects in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have  two model
Participant
Student

Student table has participantid foreign key references participant table Id.how to write a view and controller to save student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow CakePHP naming combentions? http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2006/02/18/cakephp-conventions/

Yo need to follow them form getting CakePHP magic. You said you have a **participationid** instead of **participations_id** ...  the **participant** table should be name **participants** ...

Answer (score 0):

$this->Form->input('Model.{n}.field') for has many and Model.field for has one iirc. Check out the book section on saving data, there is a bit on saving related data.

For the controller you just use saveAll() instead of save()